# 'hideSignUpLink' option doesn't hide signUp link

Tags: meteor

I downloaded a Meteor Starter project called [MeteorAdmin](https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-admin). This project uses `meteor-useraccounts` package

I would want to prevent the `"Don't have an account? Register"` sentence from appearing on the default SignIn view.

So in `accounts.coffee` I changed this:

```
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute 'signIn'
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute 'signUp'
```

to:

```
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute 'signIn' ,
  hideSignUpLink: true
AccountsTemplates.configureRoute 'signUp'
```

This did not work! Although the `meteor-useraccounts` [documentation](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#configuration-api) says it should work, hence this question

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to put it in the main configuration like so:

```
AccountsTemplates.configure({
  hideSignUpLink: true
});
```