# Where is template atSignIn defined?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-accounts

I downloaded a Meteor Starter project called [MeteorAdmin](https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-admin).

This project is using `meteor-usersaccounts` package and there's this code `{{pathFor route='atSignIn'}}` in one of the html files.

`atSignIn` is not defined anywhere, I suspect it being defines in useraccounts package but can't find it, anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lines 45-56 of [this file](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/flow-routing/blob/master/lib/core.js).

```
// Allowed routes along with theirs default configuration values
AccountsTemplates.ROUTE_DEFAULT = {
  changePwd:      { name: "atChangePwd",      path: "/change-password"},
  enrollAccount:  { name: "atEnrollAccount",  path: "/enroll-account"},
  ensureSignedIn: { name: "atEnsureSignedIn", path: null},
  forgotPwd:      { name: "atForgotPwd",      path: "/forgot-password"},
  resetPwd:       { name: "atResetPwd",       path: "/reset-password"},
  signIn:         { name: "atSignIn",         path: "/sign-in"},
  signUp:         { name: "atSignUp",         path: "/sign-up"},
  verifyEmail:    { name: "atVerifyEmail",    path: "/verify-email"},
  resendVerificationEmail: { name: "atResendVerificationEmail", path: "/send-again"}
};
```

Comment: Thank you that's helpul, I also tried customizing this page but fails, so I raised another SO question, would you be able to take a look please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342562/hidesignuplink-option-doesnt-hide-signup-link

Comment: I already shared my guess with you on #meteor irc channel. :)

Comment: I can't but laugh to this!